# some thread is can't close, socke read is block

Tags: java, sockets, java-threads

1.I use Httpclient crawl urls and use redis to count the success number, at the end, log shows that there are 29 URL did not crawl successfully and the last successful record in 3 hours ago.
2. I use jstack to see the thread information, which has 29 threads state is runnable and the stack info is following.
3. I use thread pool to execute the following method to crawl the url, method did not complete .

```
"爬取线程: 942" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe048237800 nid=0x1f69 runnable [0x00007fdf0fefe000]
         java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
         at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:264)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:225)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:184)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:213)
         at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.close(ChunkedInputStream.java:315)
         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ResponseEntityProxy.streamClosed(ResponseEntityProxy.java:140)
         at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:228)
         at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:174)
         at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(EntityUtils.java:88)
         at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(EntityUtils.java:67)
         at com.eversec.crawl.http.HttpManager.getRequest(HttpManager.java:164)
         at com.eversec.crawl.StartExec$ExecUrl.run(StartExec.java:204)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    public DomainInfo getRequest(String url) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet;
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            // 判断返回状态是否为200
            int httpResponseStateOk = 200;
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == httpResponseStateOk) {
                Header contentType = response.getEntity().getContentType();
                if (contentType != null && contentType.getValue().toLowerCase().startsWith("text/html")) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    Header[] contentLengthHeaders = response.getHeaders("Content-Length");
                    return new DomainInfo(StringUtils.getCharset(entity.getContentType().getValue()), contentBytes);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (response != null) {
                EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    builder.setConnectTimeout(properties.getConnectTimeout());
    builder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(properties.getConnectionRequestTimeout());
    builder.setSocketTimeout(properties.getSocketTimeout());
    RequestConfig config = builder.build();
```

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: in a [mcve] ! @STF carefull on what you ask ;) you could receive a lot of line of code...

Comment: @STF What exactly does [tag:pthreads] have to do with it?

Comment: @EJP my mistake...

Comment: if (response != null) {
         EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
 }

Comment: I use this method close the Inputstream, and set the setSocketTimeout 3000

Comment: @刚延峰 There is still no intelligible question here.

Comment: this is my first question, how to improve

Comment: @刚延峰 (1) ask an intelligible question (2) provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (3) revise your question and its title so it is expressed in standard English.

Comment: @EJP I found a url, this url is wired. tqfql.com. When I use httpclient access, the connection can not be properly closed